# BCP Utility: Couldnt export to text file with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

I got an issue while trying to export to text file with bcp utility. Here is my script:

```
USE [Siron_ETL]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[customer]
AS
Declare   @V_SQL_TMP     VARCHAR (4000)
SET @V_SQL_TMP = 'bcp " SELECT  INSTITUTE+H_COUNTRY+replicate('' '',3-len( H_COUNTRY)) from [Siron_ETL].[dbo].[in_customer]" queryout "C:\Customer.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -t -Slocalhost'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @V_SQL_TMP
```

However, when H_Country is NULL, i export with no data in Customer.txt. If i replace NULL value with whitespace or any character, it works. How could i export with NULL value in column.

Comment: There appears to be no relationship between something called CUSTNO and your query. Please clarify your situation.

Comment: @SMor I'm sorry. it's H_Country

Comment: What do you think will happen with `3-len(H_COUNTRY)` when `H_COUNTRY` is NULL?

Comment: I expected that when it's null. It should be replace with 3 whitespace. like '   '

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see 3 spaces in your output file for this field, then you'll need to either put the spaces in yourself, force them (with a NULLIF call)... I dont suggest this... or the better way to go, if you want this field to be consistently 3 bytes no matter what value you get (text, spaces or null) is to specify the field as char(3). Just cast the field as char(3) in your query.

SELECT  CAST( INSTITUTE+H_COUNTRY AS CHAR( 3 ) from [Siron_ETL].[dbo].[in_customer]